# How to use "hours" apex:inputField type of time

Tags: visualforce, datetime, inputfield, time

Is that possible to use only hours? below code I can have hours and minutes but I just need hours to display, is there any attribute that needs to set?

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="MyTimeController" docType="html-5.0"> 
   <apex:form>
      Enter Time: <apex:input type="time" value="{!myTime}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex:

```
public Time myTime { get; set;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to include minutes, you have to skip using `type="time"`.

Instead, use `<apex:input type="number">` with html passthrough min and max attributes as shown below. In the controller, you can get the time value by passing the hours which you get from the page.

Apex class:

```
public class sampleExtension { 

public Integer myTime { get; set;}  

public pagereference clckMe(){
    Time myTime = Time.newInstance(myTime, 0, 0, 0);
    system.debug('==================='+myTime);
    return null; } public sampleExtension (){} }
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:form >
      Enter Time: <apex:input type="number" html-min="0" html-max="23" value="{!myTime}"/>
      <apex:commandButton value="Click to get time" action="{!clckMe}"/>
</apex:form>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Time to Integer ` when I try to save the record.. understanable why i'm getting this error... since I already defined `Integer`

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: i'm trying something like this: `myTime = Time.newInstance(myTime, 0, 0, 0)` and I'm aware that myTime is Integer and thats why its failing.

Comment: You have to do like: Time myTimeTest = Time.newInstance(myTime, 0, 0, 0); And then use the myTimeTest further.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say whether you were using a custom controller. In apex, you can use `myTime.hour()` to get the hour component of a time value. I'm not certain if there's an equivalent for use in Visualforce only.

**Edit**

If you're doing this in your controller as you say, and wanted to display a time, then you should be able to use hours() on your variable if you had one that's holding a value.

The issue you appear to be having is that you're trying to input a time rather than display one. Formatting for display is much easier than assembling one input. I recommend you change your variable to a string.

```
<apex:page controller="MyTimeController" docType="html-5.0"> 
   <apex:form>
      Enter Time: <apex:input type="string" value="{!myTime}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>

public Time myTime { get; set;}
```

Then, inside your controller you can format it as hh:mm by taking myTime and adding `+:00` to it so it will look like `hh:mm`.

Comment: I'm using custom controller insteding of showing HH:MM i just want to show HH only.